# Go2Shell fails to work for macOS 12 Monterey

Tags: macos, terminal, monterey

[Go2Shell](https://zipzapmac.com/go2shell), opens a terminal window to the current directory in Finder,  fails to work for macOS 12 Monterey. Any idea how to fix it or and any alternative?

I tried [OpenInTerminal](https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal), but it fails on 12.2 too.

Comment: Go2Shell works on Monterrey 12.4 _(at least with iTerm2, haven't tried with Terminal)_. But it doesn't show an icon nor as a pickable Icon on `Customize Toolbar...`. If you click on the `>>` on the Finder, you'll see it listed as `Go2Shell.app` on the list. But if you want the icon to appear, you can delete a few of the existing icons and the white square with `>_<` should appear, then you can reorder as needed the Mac ones.

Answer (score 8):

There is a built-in Service in MacOS: "New Terminal at Folder". You can enable it and assign a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: But I use iTerm so I want to open terminal in iTerm and this seems can not be done here.

Answer (score 1):

I found this alternative https://github.com/Breathleas/Go2Shell/

BTW, I spent quite some times in finding an alternative, i.e. opens a terminal window to the current directory in Finder. It seems that go2shell and OpeninTerminal are only 2 options in the market.